# Was that the space station I saw last night?

Tags: space-station, stars

I was out on my front porch last night around 9pm looking up at the sky and noticed what I first thought was a star in the Eastern sky. It twinkled just a little too much for a star so I thought maybe an airplane.  I'm in South Florida with 2 major airports nearby and I never see planes that high in the sky so then I remembered a friend saying that sometimes you can see the space station with the naked eye.  The twinkling object high in the sky seemed to move a little faster than a star.  How would one figure out if they are looking at the space station or a star?

Comment: https://spotthestation.nasa.gov/

Comment: https://www.heavens-above.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the Satellite spotter on [in-the-sky.org](https://in-the-sky.org/satpasses.php?day=23&month=10&year=2018&mag=2&anysat=v0&group=1&s=) to be very useful for this.

According to that site, at 9pm last night (23 Oct 2018), no ISS passes or other bright satellites would have been visible from the Miami area. An old Delta II rocket stage would have been visible around 8:20pm, just about as bright as the ISS sometimes appears.

[image]